# Magento 2.4.5-p5 System.log Error: failed to parse field [must]" - How to Resolve?

Tags: error, magento2.4.5, system.log

I've encountered a recurring error in my Magento 2.4.5-p5 installation, and it's logged in the system.log file. The error message is as follows:

```
[2024-01-17T11:57:04.901592+00:00] main.ERROR: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:352] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:352] [script_score] failed to parse field [query]","caused_by":{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:352] [bool] failed to parse field [must]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"expected value but got [START_ARRAY]"}}},"status":400} [] []
```

I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this error. It seems to be related to parsing an array in the [bool] field at position [1:352]. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and what steps can be taken to resolve this error in Magento 2.4.5-p5?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I have the same issue: [2024-03-18T23:58:29.642349+00:00] main.ERROR: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:264] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:264] [bool] failed to parse field [must]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"expected value but got [START_ARRAY]"}},"status":400} [] []